# Bounding Spheres move farther than sphere object

Tags: polygon, xna-4.0, bounding-box

I have a program that I'm making with others and I ran into a problem. I'm working on adding in polygon models into our scene in an XNA window. I have that part complete. I also have bounding spheres(I know I tagged as bounding-box but there is no bounding sphere tag) drawing around each polygon. My problem is when I move the polygons around the 3D space the bounding spheres move twice as much as the polygons. I imagine its something within my polygon matrices that I use to create the bounding sphere that makes it move twice as much but that is only speculation. 
So just to clarify I'll give you an example of my problem. If I hold down D to move a polygon along the X axis. (model.position.X--;) The polygon moves as expected to but the bounding sphere around the polygon moves twice as much. Thanks for the help guys!

Here is how I draw the models and the bounding spheres:

```
       public void Draw(Matrix view, Matrix projection, bool drawBoundingSphere)
    {
        Matrix translateMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
        Matrix worldMatrix = translateMatrix * Matrix.CreateScale(scaleRatio);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.World = worldMatrix * modelAbsoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
            if (drawBoundingSphere)
            {
                // the mesh's BoundingSphere is stored relative to the mesh itself.
                // (Mesh space). We want to get this BoundingSphere in terms of world
                // coordinates. To do this, we calculate a matrix that will transform
                // from coordinates from mesh space into world space....
                Matrix world = modelAbsoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * worldMatrix;
                // ... and then transform the BoundingSphere using that matrix.
                BoundingSphere sphere = BoundingSphereRenderer.TransformBoundingSphere(mesh.BoundingSphere, world);
                // now draw the sphere with our renderer
                BoundingSphereRenderer.Draw(sphere, view, projection);
            }
        }
```

And here is the BoundingSphereRenderer Code:

```
        private static VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private static BasicEffect effect;
    private static int lineCount;
    public static void Initialize(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int sphereResolution)
    {
        // create our effect
        effect = new BasicEffect(graphicsDevice);
        effect.LightingEnabled = false;
        effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        // calculate the number of lines to draw for all circles
        lineCount = (sphereResolution + 1) * 3;
        // we need two vertices per line, so we can allocate our vertices
        VertexPositionColor[] vertices = new VertexPositionColor[lineCount * 2];
        // compute our step around each circle
        float step = MathHelper.TwoPi / sphereResolution;
        // used to track the index into our vertex array
        int index = 0;
        //create the loop on the XY plane first
        for (float angle = 0f; angle < MathHelper.TwoPi; angle += step)
        {
            vertices[index++] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle), 0f), Color.Blue);
            vertices[index++] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(angle + step), (float)Math.Sin(angle + step), 0f), Color.Blue);
        }
        //next on the XZ plane
        for (float angle = 0f; angle < MathHelper.TwoPi; angle += step)
        {
            vertices[index++] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(angle), 0f, (float)Math.Sin(angle)), Color.Red);
            vertices[index++] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3((float)Math.Cos(angle + step), 0f, (float)Math.Sin(angle + step)), Color.Red);
        }
        //finally on the YZ plane
        for (float angle = 0f; angle < MathHelper.TwoPi; angle += step)
        {
            vertices[index++] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0f, (float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle)), Color.Green);
            vertices[index++] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0f, (float)Math.Cos(angle + step), (float)Math.Sin(angle + step)), Color.Green);
        }
        // now we create the vertex buffer and put the vertices in it
        vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), vertices.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
        vertexBuffer.SetData(vertices);
    }

    public static void Draw(this BoundingSphere sphere, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        if (effect == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You must call Initialize before you can render any spheres.");
        // set the vertex buffer
        effect.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
        // update our effect matrices
        effect.World = Matrix.CreateScale(sphere.Radius) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(sphere.Center);
        effect.View = view;
        effect.Projection = projection;
        // draw the primitives with our effect
        effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        effect.GraphicsDevice.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, 0, lineCount);
    }

    public static BoundingSphere TransformBoundingSphere(BoundingSphere sphere, Matrix transform)
    {
        BoundingSphere transformedSphere;
        // the transform can contain different scales on the x, y, and z components.
        // this has the effect of stretching and squishing our bounding sphere along
        // different axes. Obviously, this is no good: a bounding sphere has to be a
        // SPHERE. so, the transformed sphere's radius must be the maximum of the 
        // scaled x, y, and z radii.
        // to calculate how the transform matrix will affect the x, y, and z
        // components of the sphere, we'll create a vector3 with x y and z equal
        // to the sphere's radius...
        Vector3 scale3 = new Vector3(sphere.Radius, sphere.Radius, sphere.Radius);
        // then transform that vector using the transform matrix. we use
        // TransformNormal because we don't want to take translation into account.
        scale3 = Vector3.TransformNormal(scale3, transform);
        // scale3 contains the x, y, and z radii of a squished and stretched sphere.
        // we'll set the finished sphere's radius to the maximum of the x y and z
        // radii, creating a sphere that is large enough to contain the original 
        // squished sphere.
        transformedSphere.Radius = Math.Max(scale3.X, Math.Max(scale3.Y, scale3.Z));
        // transforming the center of the sphere is much easier. we can just use 
        // Vector3.Transform to transform the center vector. notice that we're using
        // Transform instead of TransformNormal because in this case we DO want to 
        // take translation into account.
        transformedSphere.Center = Vector3.Transform(sphere.Center, transform);
        return transformedSphere;
    }
```

Comment: In the `BoundingSphere` draw method, what happens if you remove the radius scaling when calculating the `effect.World` matrix?

Comment: That did not work.. All that did was make the bounding sphere smaller than the polygons and when i moved the polygons they still moved twice as far as the polygon

Comment: Do the spheres move properly if you're just rotating? If it's just when they translate it seems like a translate is being scaled wrong somewhere.

Comment: well I dont have them rotating yet, just moving them on the X and Z axis is all they do. But I'll rotate them and see what happens with the sphere and bounding spheres.

Comment: Although I didn't implement the rotation of the polygons I fixed my problem. We were right when we thought something was being scaled wrong. In my polygon draw method I create a translationMatrix which equals Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) position is a vector3. Then I would make the worldMatrix which equals translationMatrix * MAtrix.CreateScale(scaleRatio) scaleRatio is a float. Now this properly scales a polygon if the user wants to. But I also used the worldMatrix to create the boundingShpere worldMatrix which caused the error. So I switched the worldMatrix with the translationMatrix

Comment: and now the boundingSphere moves with the polygons... for now. Thanks Crappy Coding Guy couldn't have done with you!